# running apps on wp7 device in Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-8

Is it possible to compile wp7 apps on the device in Windows 8 DP? The device just doesn't appear in the box (where the emulator and device usually  are), the box is empty. Is this a problem on my machine or is this a general problem? I know compiling on the emulator is not a feature of Win8, but is the device compiling included?

i.e. my device has been recognised by zune so it is connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 development is not supported on the Windows 8 Developer Preview. It is, after all, a developer preview for evaluating and providing feedback on the possible future directions of Windows 8.

Comment: tnx for the response! I know it's just a preview, but i've got feedback that wp7 compiling on the device is working(some have tested it), so the question is why is it not working for me? could it be that my Win8 is x86?

Answer (score 0):

you can't use the developer preview to install and run WP SDK.
But now WP8 SDK is out and you can install it on your W8 RTM